# Explanation and difference between Completer and Isolates in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I needed to return a Future on my app because i thought my function would be taking too much time to complete.

So i got two possible answers: Use a [Completer](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-async/Completer-class.html) or an [Isolate](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html).

What would make me choose one or the other?
Can i put a Completer anywhere i want and trust this will work fine?

And how does this work? Like.. Flutter must draw on screen in 60fps right? So, it will compute this stuff after drawing on the canvas and before the next drawing? I am curious because Flutter is not multithreaded (but appears that isolates can do this).. So i am very confused and don`t know how to write trustworthy code.

And also, is there a reason to not use a Completer? Like, i think my code is taking too much time, but maybe it is not.. Is there a reason to check the time it takes to complete and if it is below a threshold i should not use it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article helped me a lot to understand this assyncronous stuff: https://www.didierboelens.com/2019/01/futures---isolates---event-loop/

Besides explaining it with code, i think the conclusion answers my question:

> Therefore, here are some hints you should systematically take into consideration in your developments:
>
> If pieces of codes MAY NOT be interrupted, use a normal synchronous process (one method or multiple methods that call each other);
>
> If pieces of codes could run independently WITHOUT impacting the fluidity of the application, consider using the Event Loop via the use of Futures;
>
> If heavy processing might take some time to complete and could potentially impact the fluidity of the application, consider using Isolates.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a Future (Completer) ensures that the activity of your long function will be in the *same thread* as your original thread.  An Isolate is automatically in a different share-nothing thread with its own event loop, and must use message passing to access or return values.

Answer (score 0):

1. The use of a `Completer` is to obtain a value from a future that has
   not yet completed, whereas `Isolate` use to execute code in a
   separate isolate without sharing memory with other isolates.
2. `Completer` does not ensures concurrency on its own, while `Isolate`
   ensures concurrency by running code in a separate isolate.
3. Communication between different isolates requires message passing
   between the isolates, while communication between the completer and
   its associated future happens within the same isolate.